# How do I make a button disappear once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code. https://jsfiddle.net/3phzezfj/3/

```
function showhidediv(rad){
var rads=document.getElementsByName(rad.name);
document.getElementById('one').style.display=(rads[0].checked)?'block':'none' ;
document.getElementById('two').style.display=(rads[1].checked)?'block':'none' ;
document.getElementById('three').style.display=(rads[2].checked)?'block':'none' ;
    document.getElementById('four').style.display=(rads[3].checked)?'block':'none' ;
}

function switchVisible()

    {
      $("#newpost").hide();
      $("#newpost2").show();
    }

    function previousVisible()
    {
     $("#newpost").show();
        $("#newpost2").hide();
    }
```

How do I make the next button disappear once I've clicked it but if I press back, it will reappear?

Thanks.

Comment: How will you click a button that is disappeared?

Comment: @NadirLaskar MAGIC!

Comment: So you click the next button which takes you to the next form, you come to the next form and press BACK to go back to the previous form, where the next button will be

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle();

> **Description: Display or hide the matched elements.**

```
$("#newpost2").toggle();
```

If #newpost2 is hidden, it will show it, if it's shown, it will hide it.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: where do I put this in my js?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onclick` use `addEventListener` for click event.
I have edited your code here [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kmbzdy)

And you don't have to mix `js` and `jquery` like this
`document.getElementById('four')` and `$("#newpost")`
it's better to decide which one you want to use

Comment: the next button is still there?

Comment: @Harry I have updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kmbzdy) see the comments in JS part

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle was not having jquery js included.

Please check updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/3phzezfj/8/).

Attached the event handler like below.

```
$("#btnBack").click(previousVisible);
$("#btnNext").click(switchVisible);
```

And moved the Next button inside the div.

Hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want right?

```js
var check = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Button1").click(function() {
    if(check == 0)
    {
     $("#Button1").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#Button2").click(function() {
    if(check == 0)
    {
     $("#Button1").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btnSubmit {
  background-color: #7f0000;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7f0000, #6c0404);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7f0000, #6c0404);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7f0000, #6c0404);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7f0000, #6c0404);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #7f0000, #6c0404);
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bolder !important;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 2px 2px #000, 1px 1px 2px 2px #aa4242;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px 0px #090909;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid eightwidth" align="center" style="background-color: #282828; padding: 1px; padding-bottom: 0px;" id="disappear">
  <button class="btn btnSubmit" id="Button1" type="button" value="Click">NEXT</button>
  <button class="btn btnSubmit" id="Button2" type="button" value="Click">Appear</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button disappear!!

```js
$("#next").click(function(){
    $("#next").hide();
    $("#back").show();
});
$("#back").click(function() {
    $("#back").show();
    $("#next").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next"/>
<input type="button" id="back" value="Back"/>
```